# Fabric.js broken SVG with multiple paths

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

**LE: I got a solution for this.**

https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/9432

"This sounds like a precision issue. I think you should add this into your code (use a larger number if you want more precision... fabric defaults low to reduce data/memory):
fabric.Object.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS = 8;"

I am using SVG files that have been previously converted from .dxf. They contain multiple paths.
I load one svg on a canvas using **fabric.loadSVGFromString** then **fabric.util.groupSVGElements**.
Then I export the canvas content using **canvas.toSVG()**. When I load the exported SVG in browser or in Inkscape, the SVG is segmented and it seems that every path is a separate line, this is more visible when there are arcs or at corners where 2 lines join.

I am assuming this is caused by fabric.util.groupSVGElements that is splitting the loaded svg as different elements because those multiple paths.

I need a solution because I need the exported file to contain the SVG-s as they were before, with all the lines being unbroken. How can I handle this?

Steps to reproduce:

1. use ADD SVG to canvas button to load the SVG to the bottom canvas (red border canvas)
2. use Display Exported Canvas button to export the red border canvas content with toSVG() - its content will be loaded to the blue border div

**Expected results**: the svg lines remain unbroken as the svg is initially

**Actual results**: the svg lines are broken, this is visible when using zoom in :(

[svg before and after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhA5M.png)

More **details** and jsfiddle link: https://groups.google.com/g/fabricjs/c/O1HtbMOnOck
or jsfiddle: /IoanaBraica/m4n8uoex/78/

I tried multiple ways to load this svg using fabric. Loading it as a Image is not a solution, because after manipulating the svg on canvas, I have to convert it back to DXF and that is not possible having the result as a Image.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by rounding errors in some transformation/translate values.

Apparently, fabric.js calculates translate values rounded to 2 decimals.

As a workaround, you might combine all paths before loading them to your fabric.js canvas.

```js
/**
 * combine paths helper
 */
function combinePaths(svgMarkup) {
  let svg = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svgMarkup, "text/html").querySelector("svg");
  let paths = svg.querySelectorAll("path");
  let firstPath = paths[0];

  let dCombined = "";
  paths.forEach((path, i) => {
    let d = path.getAttribute("d");
    dCombined += d;
    if (i > 0) {
      path.remove();
    }
  });
  firstPath.setAttribute("d", dCombined);
  let newSVG = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
  return newSVG;
}



var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canv");
var svg = `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
  <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd"[]>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="body_-601143644_6578" width="6.815056473908554in" height="1.7112020646806974in">
    <g transform="matrix(95.500792 0 0 -95.500792 1.7010636 82.138042)">
      <g>
        <path d="M-4.7087673E-09 0.28821083L0.0073893023 0.25296545L0.01721924 0.21832137L0.029441858 0.18444738L0.04399764 0.15150853L0.060815657 0.11966527L0.079813982 0.08907274L0.10090004 0.059879965L0.12397115 0.032229221L0.14891486 0.0062551864L0.17560967 -0.017915599L0.20392551 -0.040165357L0.23372447 -0.060385697L0.26486131 -0.07847812L0.29718438 -0.094354503L0.33053619 -0.10793744L0.33140596 -0.10825585" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M0 0.51393133L0 0.2882109" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M0.31213705 0.85560461L0.28350142 0.84688668L0.25554367 0.83619245L0.22840002 0.82357406L0.20220271 0.80909293L0.17707937 0.79281967L0.15315239 0.77483352L0.13053833 0.75522213L0.10934739 0.73408105L0.089682809 0.71151324L0.071640364 0.68762868L0.055307976 0.66254372L0.040765217 0.63638057L0.028082929 0.60926672L0.017322919 0.58133422L0.0085375825 0.5527192L0.0017697135 0.52356105L-7.9355301E-09 0.51393123" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M2.4203046 0.23280891L2.383579 0.22032561L2.3478136 0.20531084L2.3131828 0.18783777L2.2798551 0.16799154L2.2479931 0.14586883L2.2177518 0.1215774L2.1892787 0.095235669L2.1627125 0.066971892L2.1381825 0.036923819L2.1158084 0.0052378119L2.0956991 -0.027931725L2.0779526 -0.062423249L2.0626552 -0.098068675L2.0498817 -0.13469435L2.0396942 -0.17212187L2.0321422 -0.21016884L2.0272628 -0.24864994L2.0250795 -0.28737767L2.025603 -0.32616336L2.0288307 -0.36481806L2.0347471 -0.40315344L2.0433232 -0.44098272L2.0545172 -0.47812162L2.0682746 -0.5143892L2.0845285 -0.54960877L2.1031995 -0.58360872L2.1241967 -0.61622343L2.1474179 -0.64729399L2.1727499 -0.67666906L2.2000693 -0.70420548L2.229243 -0.72976911L2.2601289 -0.75323546L2.2925764 -0.77449012L2.3264276 -0.79342958L2.3615174 -0.80996159L2.397675 -0.82400557L2.4347242 -0.83549312L2.4471617 -0.83872452" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M0.82451884 0.28686318L0.82031025 0.25443185L0.81384958 0.22237308L0.80516837 0.1908431L0.79430892 0.15999548L0.78132404 0.12998053L0.76627709 0.10094445L0.74924134 0.073028757L0.73029979 0.046369387L0.7095447 0.021096273L0.68707721 -0.0026674726L0.66300677 -0.024806068L0.63745068 -0.045211688L0.6105334 -0.063784883L0.58238608 -0.080435202L0.55314587 -0.095081494L0.52295521 -0.10765241L0.52134138 -0.10825581" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M3.2709704 0.23280893L3.2709704 -0.40736173" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M2.4471617 -0.83872457L2.4876074 -0.84711339L2.5285397 -0.85266043L2.5697593 -0.85533871L2.6110653 -0.8551351L2.6522564 -0.85205068L2.6931321 -0.84610035L2.7334931 -0.83731319L2.7731429 -0.82573201L2.8118882 -0.81141324L2.8495403 -0.79442658L2.8859157 -0.77485479L2.9208373 -0.75279333L2.9541349 -0.72834955L2.9856462 -0.70164262L3.0152178 -0.67280261L3.0427056 -0.64197005L3.0679757 -0.60929515L3.0909049 -0.57493706L3.1113816 -0.53906323L3.1293059 -0.5018484L3.1445906 -0.46347389L3.1571613 -0.42412666L3.1616152 -0.40736167" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M3.1616152 -0.40736173L3.2709704 -0.40736173" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M0.33140589 -0.10825581L0.52134137 -0.10825581" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M0.82451883 0.28686319L1.9041929 0.28686319" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M0.82451883 0.41322856L1.9041929 0.41322856" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M0.82451885 0.41322856L0.81972855 0.44893116L0.8124594 0.48421263L0.80274686 0.51890108L0.79063823 0.55282752L0.77619251 0.58582668L0.75948008 0.61773775L0.74058234 0.6484053L0.71959137 0.67767991L0.69660946 0.70541896L0.67174854 0.73148726L0.64512976 0.75575788L0.61688279 0.77811254L0.58714523 0.79844235L0.55606199 0.81664823L0.52378451 0.8326415L0.49047 0.84634425L0.46320459 0.85560466" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M0.31213707 0.85560463L0.4632046 0.85560463" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M3.2709704 0.23280893L6.8150564 0.23280893" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M6.8150564 0.46596293L6.8150564 0.23280893" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M2.5330992 0.46596293L6.8150564 0.46596293" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M2.4203046 0.26479106L2.4203046 0.23280893" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M2.5330992 0.46596293L2.5330992 0.43739009" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M1.9041929 0.43739009L2.5330992 0.43739009" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M1.9041929 0.26479106L2.4203046 0.26479106" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M1.9041929 0.28686319L1.9041929 0.26479106" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
        <path d="M1.9041929 0.43739009L1.9041929 0.41322856" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.001481663" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>`;

canvas.setWidth(1000);
canvas.setHeight(1000);

function exportSVG() {
  let mySvg = canvas.toSVG();
  canvas.includeDefaultValues = false;
  const res = document.getElementById("result");
  console.log(mySvg);
  res.innerHTML = mySvg;
}

function add() {
  //combine paths
  let svgMerged = combinePaths(svg);

  fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgMerged, function (objects, options) {
    var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

    canvas.add(obj);
    canvas.setActiveObject(obj);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  });
}
```

```css
#result {
    border: 2px solid blue;
}

#canv {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="result">
    Result:
</div>

<button id="svg" onclick="add()" type="submit">
    ADD SVG to canvas (all good)
</button>
<button id="order" onclick="exportSVG()" type="button">
    Display Exported Canvas (lines are separated - use zoom in to see it)
</button>   

<canvas id="canv" class="cv" style="width: 2400px; height: 2400px"></canvas>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually got a easier solution for this: "This sounds like a precision issue. I think you should add this into your code (use a larger number if you want more precision... fabric defaults low to reduce data/memory):
fabric.Object.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS = 8;" https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/9432